# Reactjs UseState with Socketio-client

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm creating a project with `python flask api` that runs on local computer since I also have a function that communicates through `pymodbus`. I'm using `socketio` to continuously transfer the data to my frontend for visualization.

testing the data I'm retrieving from the machine/plc using python and printing the data I got using `console.log` cause no issues.

My problem is that when I try to put the data on a `const` using `useState` I get an error `Websocket connection to '<address>' failed: Invalid Frame Header` and my connection to the machine is getting severed.

Here is the code on how I connect to the backend api using `socketio-client`

```
const [lights, setLights] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const socket = io.connect(`${PATH}/rt-plc-data` )

  socket.emit("plcEvent")
  socket.on("response", data => {
    console.log(data.stopLights[0])
    // setLights(data.stopLights)
  })

  return () => {
    socket.disconnect()
  }
})
```

I also noticed that when I put the data on a `const` the socket-io keeps on creating a poll.

Comment: so your trying to receive data from the response and set the lights variable ?

Comment: Yes, is there something wrong with the code? @JimClayton

Comment: could i get a little bit more code ?

Comment: This is the only code I have for the `reactjs` that fetches data from the `api`. Are you referring to the backend socket-io code?